# Combinaciones de caracteres sin permutar

Tags: vb.net, algoritmos

Tengo la string,

**123456789**

y necesito crear todas las combinaciones posibles. No me sirven las permutaciones o cambiarle el orden a los caracteres.

Si la string fuese:

123

debería quedar una lista como esta:

123

23
 13
 12
 3
 2
 1

Tengo lo siguiente. Pero es para consola y no funciona bien.
Necesito cambiarlo para que funcione con WindowsForm

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim cifras As String = "123456789"

        For k As Integer = 1 To cifras.Length
            Combina(cifras.ToCharArray, k)
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Combina(letras() As Char, grupo As Integer)
        Dim c(grupo) As Integer

        While c(0) < letras.Length - grupo + 1
            For k = 0 To grupo - 1
                Dim n As Char = letras(k + c(k))

                If k = grupo - 1 Then
                    c(k) += 1
                    If c(k) > letras.Length - grupo Then
                        Dim j As Integer = k

                        While j > 0 And c(j) > letras.Length - grupo
                            c(j - 1) += 1
                            j -= 1
                        End While

                        For m As Integer = j + 1 To grupo - 1
                            c(m) = c(j)
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
                Console.Write(n)
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        End While

    End Sub

End Module
```

**Edito**

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
    Public Sub Combina(letras() As Char, grupo As Integer)
        Dim c(grupo) As Integer
        Dim n As Char
        Dim j As Integer
        While c(0) < letras.Length - grupo + 1
            For k = 0 To grupo - 1
                n = letras(k + c(k))
                If k = grupo - 1 Then
                    c(k) += 1
                    If c(k) > letras.Length - grupo Then
                        j = k
                        While j > 0 And c(j) > letras.Length - grupo
                            c(j - 1) += 1
                            j -= 1
                        End While
                        For m As Integer = j + 1 To grupo - 1
                            c(m) = c(j)
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
                Label1.Text = (n)
            Next
        End While
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        Dim cifras As String = "123"
        For k As Integer = 1 To cifras.Length
            Combina(cifras.ToCharArray, k)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Label1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.TextChanged
        ListBox3.Items.Add(Label1.Text)
        TextBox7.Text += Label1.Text
    End Sub
'El resultado en WindowsForm no es el esperado:
'Resultado
'1
'2
'3
'1
'2
'1
'3
'2
'3
'1
'2
'3
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que quieres mostrar las 999999999 +1 alternativas? Por otro lado, si ya tienes el código funcionando en consola, ¿qué has intentado para pasar a Windows Forms? los métodos son los mismo, pasar parámetros solamente y usar algún controlador para renderizar el resultado. ¿Has visto la documentación oficial?

Comment: Pone lo que pusiste como respuesta en la pregunta. El error es como lo estas mostrando.. el algoritmo anda perfecto.

Comment: Como tengo que mostrarlo para que me ande bien en WindowsForm?

Comment: Gracias gbianchi. Publico la respuesta para que la necesite.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es puramente de vista. Vos estas agregando de a 1 los elementos a un textbox, y despues creaste un evento cada vez que cambia el textbox, que pasa inmediatemente el valor a una lista.

Esto es casi lo que queres. Vos en la consola, escribias numeros y una vez que terminabas, le dabas un enter (el WriteLine).

Hagamos algo similar en la pantalla.

En lugar de esto:

```
Label1.Text = (n)
```

Hace esto:

```
Label1.Text = Label1.Text & (n)
```

Y luego del next que cierra el for, hace:

```
ListBox3.Items.Add(Label1.Text)
Label1.Text = ""
```

Y elimina el evento `Label1_TextChanged`.

### Nota:

Esto igual lo podrias haber hecho en variables, en lugar de usar el label como variable.

Comment: Seguro que si. Seria mas rápido todavía. Pero estoy empezando y con poco tiempo. Gracias de nuevo